# Adjust usort function to sort on one of 2 fields

Tags: php

I have two types of array's fields that I want to sort according to:

1st is **registration_date** and second is **preregistration_date**

and here is the print_r array output (stored in variable **$unsorted_users**):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 120
            [registration_date] => 2012-10-19 16:57:46
            [username] => Jeff
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 121
            [preregistration_date] => 2012-12-23 16:57:46

        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 122
            [registration_date] => 2012-11-30 16:57:46
            [username] => Susan
        )

)
```

I want to order this array **DESC** by **registration_date** and **preregistration_date** so it looks like this:

Array
    (
         [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 121
                [preregistration_date] => 2012-12-23 16:57:46

```
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 122
            [registration_date] => 2012-11-30 16:57:46
            [username] => Susan

        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 120
            [registration_date] => 2012-10-19 16:57:46
            [username] => Jeff

        )

)
```

And my usort function is:

```
$sorted_users = usort($unsorted_users, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp ($a->registration_date, $b->registration_date) ;
});
```

But, It is sorting just by **registration_date** and if there is no registration_date e.g.:

```
 [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 121
                [preregistration_date] => 2012-12-23 16:57:46

            )
```

I get an error.

How to adjust my function so it is registration_date or preregistation_date sorting?

Btw. format of registration_date and preregistration_date is always the same and also both cannot be in one object. So, this doesn't need to be validated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `property_exists()` to check whether a property exists before trying to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$sorted_users = usort($unsorted_users, function($a, $b) {
   $registrationDateA = empty($a->registration_date) ? 
      $a->preregistration_date : $a->registration_date;
   $registrationDateB = empty($b->registration_date) ? 
      $b->preregistration_date : $b->registration_date;
   return strcmp ($registrationDateA, registrationDateB) ;
});
```

Comment: Looks like the right way to do it. I will try it a let you know how it wokrs.